# Why is there a perfectly straight line at the edge of this knot?

Tags: knots

This is a bit of a cheat because I am not a 'woodworking' enthusiast, but our company does make furniture. My question is simple. In the photo .. why is there a really straight line (that looks almost like a joined piece of wood) through this knot here. I've even asked the manufacturer and she says that it is natural (but she's not 100% sure so she's going to look into it). Just wondering if anyone could lend any advice here? She showed me some other photos of timber which also has really straight lines. The wood is FSC acacia.

Of course there doesn't seem to be any rational explanation for going to all that time to join two thin little bits of wood together. So it presumably is natural.

Thanks

p.s. I couldn't see a forum for manufacturing .. there was one called The Workplace but didn't seem appropriate.

[image: Straight Line through Knot]

Comment: "I am not a 'woodworking' enthusiast"  Does this mean you are a 'woodworking' un-enthusiast, *I.E. You are not very enthusiastic about your woodworking?* **Words !** I am an etymology enthusiast.  ( *i know un-enthusiast is not a word, ironic isn't it ?* )

Comment: haha :) thanks for sharing

Comment: but simply, I do not possess the property of being enthusiastic about woodworking. If somebody say, Hey man do you feel enthusiastic about woodworking - I would have to say, no not really. I'm more into my manufacturing :)

Comment: But how many friends do you have ... or how many 'unfriends' do you have? Presumably you can have Unfriends on Facebook who you have unfriended, though presumably a friend is somebody you are friendly with and an unfriend is somebody you are unfriendly with

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That board is actually two separate boards that have been glued together.  When one of them was ripped (i.e. cut lengthwise) it went through the knot.

You can see that along the entire length of that slat none of the grain flows through that seam.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So presumably the factory would have glued those together - they wouldn't have purchased the timber like that? Right so after they cut it lengthways, it went through the knot which obviously caused problems. So is that why they had to 'fix' it with this thin panel - and save losing the piece entirely? Sorry have I got the general idea? Thanks for your time

Comment: Also thanks for the tip about the grain

Comment: Yeah the motivation isn't as easy to determine.  Wood goes through many hands before it becomes furniture, and there's no way to tell when the issue (having a knot on the edge of the board) came up and when someone decided to fix it by gluing another board to it.

Comment: Okay. Great. I suppose they might have just had a thin piece left over and didn't want to waste it.. i.e. thinner than the slat width.. and too thin to use with any other products. Or as you say, it could be something like when they cut the timber to the right width they are always just left with some thin bits .. and they felt it would be a good opportunity to use one and cut costs.. (I mean, the left-hand piece might have been the one that was 'left-over'). Anyway, I'll find out more tomorrow.